# in excel check a column with text value if true return numeric value in next column

Tags: excel

I have two columns, A, B and C,

Column A has two text values "Petrol" & "Butane" 
column B has just numeric values (i.e their cost in USD)

I need to run a formula in column C so i can check column A for "Petrol" and check corresponding rows in Column B for their value and then get a SUM of those numeric values as a total cost in column C

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Wouldn't you just add the values using `SUM()`?

Answer (score 2):

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Petrol",B:B)
```

And

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Butane",B:B)
```

Any cell you put this in will return the sum of all cells in column B where the value on the same row but in column A is equal to the word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ISTEXT function

=ISTEXT(A2) Checks to see if cell A2 has text (TRUE)